# If spent money on a patent application that went nowhere. Can I count it as a loss in my tax return?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction

It was almost 4k. This would be considered a business loss, no? Can I deduct that from my taxes?

Comment: Is filing patents part of your business? Or it's a one-off?

Comment: It's a one-off. It was the precursor to starting the business, but it went nowhere.

Comment: Was the patent actually granted?

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments which now appear to be covered in the answers or comments on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

Patent costs should be amortized over the expected usefulness period of the patent (See [26 CFR 1.167(a)-6](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.167(a)-6)). Costs include all the expenses related to the patent application, or the costs of patent purchase. R&D to come up with the idea is **not** considered part of patent costs, R&D expenses are also amortized, but differently and separately. Patent expected usefulness period is essentially the period during which the patent can be enforced (usually 15-20 years for a newly approved patent).

In your case you don't have any viable business, and never expected to gain any income from the patent (and no, filing the patent doesn't show business intent). So it's a hobby. Unless you actually file for enforcement and start receiving license fees, or start manufacturing and producing the patented product, there's no business and no deductions.

Comment: If he files a Schedule C then he does have the intent of a significant business. A simple 16-word comment, in response to a pointed question, doesn't disprove the intent.

Comment: @SSpring filing schedule C isn't enough and the IRS routinely disallows schedule C expenses when the taxpayer cannot show that there's an actual business behind them. I.e.: actual business activity over time with intent (and ability) to gain profits.

Comment: Did you consider the effect of "If a patent or copyright becomes valueless in any year before its expiration the unrecovered cost or other basis may be deducted in that year" in the CFR link you posted?

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica that's not the case here. Valueless means cannot be enforced, i.e.: invalidated by the patent office or courts. The case here is abandonment, which is a choice and not a necessity and as such doesn't change the amortization schedule (similarly to IRC Sec. 174(d) for R&D expenses, which can also not be written off).

Answer (score 0):

"Ordinary and necessary business expenses of ... creators of intellectual property are deductible under Sec. 162."

"On the other hand, patent creation costs must be capitalized under Sec. 263 or in certain cases may be deductible as research expenditures under Sec. 174."

https://www.thetaxadviser.com/issues/2013/dec/kelley-dec2013.html

Well, I wouldn't be able to keep a straight face while telling someone that they must amortize the cost of a composition of a legal document. A patent filing is just a document that describes a development. The lawyer that writes the document is just a legal expert relating the development and doing so for ordinary legal fee.

But if it is a failed patent application then it can't be amortized as patent cost but can only be a legal expense. Or as R&D write-off.

https://www.thetaxadviser.com/issues/2018/nov/loss-deductions-abandonment-intangible-assets.html

Comment: That's just plain wrong, I'm sorry. You may think that it's "just a document" but the laws and regulations are quite explicit on how patent applications should be handled in this regard because it's not "just" a document. If you can't handle keeping a straight face when telling people how taxes in the US work - don't try then.

Comment: patent application doesn't create any new intellectual property. Creators of intellectual property are musicians, writers, painters, etc. Not patent lawyers. What you're talking about is not just legal fee of the drafting attorney, but a whole amount of total expenses to get a patent - a guaranteed right enforceable in courts. That's what you're paying for, not drafting a document.

Comment: A failed patent filing can't have a cost amortized over its life because it doesn't have a life. Well, a failed patent filing doesn't have a life beyond a patent-pending period. https://www.thetaxadviser.com/issues/2018/nov/loss-deductions-abandonment-intangible-assets.html

Comment: If the patent was denied then the remaining costs not yet amortized can be deducted in that year, but usually it takes years for the patent office to reach a decision, and until then you amortize the incurred costs.